# Filter CSV where column is greater or equal to a number

Tags: powershell, int, filtering, import-csv

I have the following CSV file :

```
"Count";"Computername";"Files and paths"
"3";"Computer1";"%OSDRIVE%\USERS\0000008\APPDATA\LOCAL\TEMP\__PSSCRIPT.PS1"
"1";"Computer1";"%OSDRIVE%\USERS\0000008\APPDATA\LOCAL\TEMP\__PSSCRIPT.PS1"
"5";"Computer3";"\\SRV\TOTO$\HELLO.BAT"
"8";"Computer4";"\\192.168.8.18\TOTO\DNS.BAT"
"10";"Computer15";"%OSDRIVE%\Hello.exe"
"12";"Computer6";"\\SRV\SCRIPTS\REBOOT.BAT"
"88";"Computer7";"%OSDRIVE%\Winword.exe"
"154";"Computer2";"%OSDRIVE%\excel.exe"
```

I want to keep all the line where the "Count" is superior or equal to 8.

I've tried the following command :

```
Import-Csv -Path MyFile.csv -Delimiter ";" | Where-Object {$_.Count -ge 8}
```

But it only returns to me the lines whith 8 or 88 or 18... but not all the other lines superiors to 8 (like 10, 12, 154 ...).

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless type information is embedded ([see documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv?view=powershell-6#notes)), every value becomes string. This leads to alphabetical comparisons instead of integer one. See following:

```
$csv = ConvertFrom-Csv @'
"Count";"Computername";"Files and paths"
"3";"Computer1";"%OSDRIVE%\USERS\0000008\APPDATA\LOCAL\TEMP\__PSSCRIPT.PS1"
"1";"Computer1";"%OSDRIVE%\USERS\0000008\APPDATA\LOCAL\TEMP\__PSSCRIPT.PS1"
"5";"Computer3";"\\SRV\TOTO$\HELLO.BAT"
"8";"Computer4";"\\192.168.8.18\TOTO\DNS.BAT"
"10";"Computer15";"%OSDRIVE%\Hello.exe"
"12";"Computer6";"\\SRV\SCRIPTS\REBOOT.BAT"
"88";"Computer7";"%OSDRIVE%\Winword.exe"
"154";"Computer2";"%OSDRIVE%\excel.exe"
'@ -Delimiter ';'

$csv | gm
```

All properties are strings:

```
   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name            MemberType   Definition                                                                      
----            ----------   ----------                                                                      
Equals          Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)                                                  
GetHashCode     Method       int GetHashCode()                                                               
GetType         Method       type GetType()                                                                  
ToString        Method       string ToString()                                                               
Computername    NoteProperty string Computername=Computer1                                                   
Count           NoteProperty string Count=3                                                                  
Files and paths NoteProperty string Files and paths=%OSDRIVE%\USERS\0000008\APPDATA\LOCAL\TEMP\__PSSCRIPT.PS1
```

The easiest solution is to use casting:

```
$csv | Where-Object {[int]$_.Count -ge 8}
```

Comment: To elaborate on that PowerShell tries to cast the right hand side of a comparison to the type of the left hand side, so reversing the order and logic  - this will work: `$csv | Where-Object {8 -le $_.Count }`

Answer (score 1):

`Count` is read a string so you need to change it to an integer for your comparison to work.

One way is to change your `Where-Object` statement to

```
where {($_.Count -as [int]) -ge 8}
```